# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'field list' error message while trying to update datas in database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a Console Shell script in CakePHP 2.6 which updates datas in a specified table while retrieving elements from a feed.

Unfortunately, I am getting an error from the update query :

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'GBP' in 'field list'
```

This is the update query :

```
$this->VendorCurrency->updateAll(
    $data, 
    array(
        'VendorCurrency.vendor_id =' => $vendorid,                          
        'VendorCurrency.curr_to =' => $update['currency_code'], 
        'VendorCurrency.curr_from =' => self::BASE_CURRENCY
    )
 );
```

And :

```
$vendorid = 88;

$datas = Array
(
    [VendorCurrency.curr_from] => GBP
    [VendorCurrency.curr_to] => CAD
    [VendorCurrency.sell_rate] => 1.957
    [VendorCurrency.buy_rate] => 2.028
)

$update['currency_code'] = 'CAD';

self::BASE_CURRENCY = 'GBP';
```

I am fairly new with CakePHP, so bear with me if this is a silly issue, am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: seems you have some typos (`$datar` instead of `$datas` and a comma missing between `$datar` and `array`). Are them just in the questions or this is your actual code?

Comment: Yes, sorry I mis-copied that statement, I corrected it, but the error is not coming from this.

Comment: Hi , can you provide query not only error part ?

Answer (score 1):

From [the official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions):

> The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually using DboSource::value(). For example if one of your model methods was calling updateAll() you would do the following:

Example, as well from the documentation, that shows how to escape the fields:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$value = $db->value($value, 'string');
$this->updateAll(
    array('Baker.something' => $value),
    array('Baker.active' => true)
);
```

Also the `=` is not needed in your conditions array.

Comment: What is not clear there? I think it's pretty clear if you don't stop reading after the first paragraph and example.

Comment: the _fields_ array accepts sql expressions, [the conditions do not need quoting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/29iDp.png) - the example you are quoting in the book [is wrong](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTaGf.png).

Comment: Updated it and created an issue report for the docs. https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues/3392

Comment: There's a pr pending, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked in CakePHP but it looks like you need to have the array values wrapped in single quotes to make it work.

`$datas = Array
(
    [VendorCurrency.curr_from] => 'GBP'
    [VendorCurrency.curr_to] => 'CAD'
    [VendorCurrency.sell_rate] => 1.957
    [VendorCurrency.buy_rate] => 2.028
)`

Comment: You might have the right idea, but it's hard to tell. `I have not worked in CakePHP` - probably _not_ a good idea to answer questions on something you aren't familiar with =).